# What does “Nitwit! Blubber! Oddment! Tweak!” mean?

Tags: harry-potter, albus-dumbledore

> Welcome to a new year at Hogwarts! Before we begin our banquet, I would like to say a few words. And here they are: **Nitwit! Blubber! Oddment! Tweak!** Thank you."
>
> (Albus Dumbldore, at the opening of welcome feast, *Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone*).

Did Rowling ever reveal what exactly the meaning behind those 4 words are?

Or were they literally randomly picked just for "mad genius" effect?

Comment: Please note that I'm familiar with the theory in this essay (http://www.hogwartsprofessor.com/nitwit-blubber-oddment-tweak-four-words-for-other/) but am looking for a canon/JKR info, not random guesses.

Comment: Oy, talk about stretching to make a point. They're four words, chosen to sound as random as possible. It's the speech, i.e. the taking of "I would like to say a few words" utterly literally, that made an impression on Harry, not the words themselves.

Comment: after 6 pages of google, i have found no quotes by JKR in reference to this. :(

Comment: This is just another rehash of a VERY old joke. Example: [this Garfield strip from 1982](http://images.ucomics.com/comics/ga/1982/ga820501.gif)

Comment: In the Dutch translation they're "Domkop! Blubber! Kleinood! Kriel!" (Nitwit, mud/slush, jewel/gem/trinket, small potato).

Comment: In Italian, "Pigna, pizzicotto, manicotto, tigre" (pinecone, tweak/pinch, muff, tiger). Only the tweak matches, but everything's better with rhymes :)

Comment: You know how some professors start off by making a silly joke? It makes all the students groan, and it makes the professor laugh inside at a successful student-groaner? Ladies and gents, Dumbledore.

Comment: There is a similar, but even older joke in the children's classic, [_The Phantom Tollbooth_](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?17229), by Norton Juster (1961). The protagonist, a boy named Milo, is invited to dine with King Azaz of Dictionopolis. As guest of honor, Milo is asked to speak first, and he manages a few dry words of thanks before being cut off. Everyone else rattles off a dinner order, ending with the King's elaborate order in French. Milo did not realize that he would have to eat his own words, and he looks unhappily at his plate as everyone else gets appetizing dinners.

Answer (score 17):

I don't think one should read too much into these words - to me this is just Dumbledore being eccentric for humorous effect, to entertain the students.  It is a kind of joke, taking the phrase 'a few words' extremely literally.

Actually, this reminds me of an old Groucho Marx joke: 'When I first came to the United States, I didn't have a nickel in my pocket.' *(reaches into pocket and pulls out a coin)* 'Now I HAVE a nickel in my pocket.'

Comment: Do you not think they could reflect the traits of the other houses like in the article linked under the question?

Comment: Hi PMar, I noticed that you have a huge number of unregistered accounts with the same name and gravatar. **Please consider merging your accounts** by following [these instructions](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). With a single unified account, you would have more site privileges, such as being able to vote on other people's posts, leave comments everywhere, or even edit any post.